# Need help remembering a young adult sci fi book

Tags: story-identification

I read this several years ago, around 2012 to 2014. The cover had a boy with his back facing the reader, looking at something inside his spaceship. The story began with him waking up from stasis and the ship being under attack, I don't really remember the middle of the story. The planet was forested and I believe he and some other characters, one of which may have been part of the alien race (which was humaniod) found a massive spire that they went into, and awoke a sphere or some other kind of flying thing which they needed to follow. It also had several illustrations, and was probably about 200 pages long, 300 at max. It is discovered that there is another alien race that poses a threat to both humanity and the warring faction. There was an illustration at the end of a massive creature/spaceship with a cavernous opening that dwarfed the boys spaceship. 
Any help would be great, thanks!